# Disable IPv6 on Interface in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: networking, debian, ipv6

I'm working on Debian Wheezy:

```
$ uname -a
Linux openstack1 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.51-1 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I set up two networks for VirtualBox:

```
# Public network vboxnet0 (10.1.0.0/16)
VBoxManage hostonlyif create
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet0 --ip 10.1.0.254 --netmask 255.255.0.0

# Private network vboxnet1 (10.2.0.0/16)
VBoxManage hostonlyif create
VBoxManage hostonlyif ipconfig vboxnet1 --ip 10.2.0.254 --netmask 255.255.0.0
...

# VirtualBox Network
VBoxManage modifyvm openstack1 --nic1 nat \
  --nic2 hostonly --hostonlyadapter2 vboxnet0 \
  --nic3 hostonly --hostonlyadapter3 vboxnet1
```

In the virtual machine, I have the following in `/etc/network/interfaces`:

```
# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# Primary network interface
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

# Public network (OpenStack)
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
    address 10.1.0.10
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.1.0.0
    broadcast 10.1.255.255

# Private network (OpenStack)
auto eth2
iface eth2 inet static
    address 10.2.0.10
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    network 10.2.0.0
    broadcast 10.2.255.255
```

When I examine the interface configuration, IPv6 is enabled:

```
$ sudo ifconfig
[sudo] password for openstack: 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:6f:c5:38  
          inet addr:172.16.1.23  Bcast:172.31.255.255  Mask:255.240.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe6f:c538/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:614 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:61279 (59.8 KiB)  TX bytes:13336 (13.0 KiB)

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:79:99:40  
          inet addr:10.1.0.10  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fe79:9940/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5288 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:8485 (8.2 KiB)

eth2      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:00:27:f1:7b:f5  
          inet addr:10.2.0.10  Bcast:10.2.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::a00:27ff:fef1:7bf5/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:35 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:55 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:5288 (5.1 KiB)  TX bytes:8690 (8.4 KiB)
```

`man 5 interfaces` does not discuss how to disable IPv6 on an interface. The [Debian IPv6 Project](https://wiki.debian.org/DebianIPv6) does not specify how to disable IPv6 for Wheezy (only kernel level for Squeeze).

In the absence of documentation, I tried adding a `off` and `disable` to `eth1` and `eth2`, but it resulted in an error:

```
iface eth1 inet6 off
```

(Apparently, the above stanza completely broke networking because I get nothing out of `ifconfig` and `ping` does not work. Additionally, `eth0` and `lo` are down even though they were not modified.).

What do I add to `/etc/network/interfaces` to disable IPv6 on the interfaces I have configured?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to disable IPv6 on Debian Wheezy?](http://superuser.com/q/546788/53590)

Comment: Thanks Michael. Its close, but not quite. I'm looking to disable it for the interface I configured, and not the kernel.

Comment: If you will be happy with blocking IPv6 (not disabling), than you can use `ip6tables` to block input and output IPv6 completely, but interface still will be listening to IPv6.

Comment: Another possible solution: as per [Linux IPv6 HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Linux%2BIPv6-HOWTO/x1050.html) there is possibility to remove an IPv6 address with command `# /sbin/ifconfig <interface> inet6 del <ipv6address>/<prefixlength>`. I disabled IPv6 in my kernel, so I could not test it. Anyway, try it and let us know.

Comment: Why are you trying to disable IPv6 on an interface? You almost certainly don't need to do this.

Comment: Thanks Michael. "Why are you trying to disable IPv6 on an interface" - my little lab only provides IPv4, so there's no need for IPv6. IP v6 uses additional resources and increases attack surface. Plus it creates a lot of noise during wireshark traces. I guess I could volley it back over the net: why would people run something they don't want or need?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

According to [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/309463), the following in `/etc/sysctl.conf` should disable IPv6 on all interfaces :

```
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Edit: for only one interface, the following should do the trick (replace `<interface>` with the interface's name) :

```
net.ipv6.conf.<interface>.disable_ipv6 = 1
```

Comment: You may need to run `sudo sysctl -p` after making the above changes.  (Or, alternatively, you could reboot.)