# clients don't connect to squid server

Tags: networking, windows-10, debian, proxy, squid

I'm currently trying to make a squid server on my personal laptop to allow a few PC's on my work to connect to the internet through a vpn on my laptop.

I've installed and configured squid on my laptop running Debian 9, and connected my laptop to my work LAN (IP = 10.75.245.21).

Then I've configured a PC running Windows 10 (IP = 10.75.245.20) to use the proxy on my computer (port = 3128). But when I try to access any internet page the conexion fails.

any ideas on how to fix it?

Adicional information

All computers in the LAN have fixed IP with the subnet mask 255.255.254.0 The network here also have internet access but has a very strict firewall (the motive I want to route connections through VPN) All computers and my laptop are in the same subnet My computer is also connected to a wireless network. I am using a cisco protocol VPN on my computer

when I try to open an internet page the command netstat -na | grep 3128 on my computer (server) shows:

```
    tcp6       0      0 :::3128                 :::*                    LISTEN
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52802      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52803      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52798      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52806      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52804      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52805      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52801      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52800      SYN_RECV
    tcp6       0      0 10.75.245.21:3128       10.75.245.20:52799      SYN_RECV
```

and the netstat command in the client shows:

```
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52798     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52799     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52800     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52801     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52802     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52803     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52804     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52805     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
    TCP    10.75.245.20:52806     10.75.245.21:3128      ESTABLISHED
```

Thnx for any help!

edit1: cache.log file:

```
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Starting Squid Cache version 3.5.23 for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu...
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Service Name: squid
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Process ID 8839
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Process Roles: worker
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| With 65535 file descriptors available
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Initializing IP Cache...
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| DNS Socket created at [::], FD 6
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| DNS Socket created at 0.0.0.0, FD 8
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Adding nameserver 192.10.15.1 from /etc/resolv.conf
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Logfile: opening log daemon:/var/log/squid/access.log
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Logfile Daemon: opening log /var/log/squid/access.log
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Local cache digest enabled; rebuild/rewrite every 3600/3600 sec
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Store logging disabled
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Swap maxSize 0 + 262144 KB, estimated 20164 objects
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Target number of buckets: 1008
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Using 8192 Store buckets
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Max Mem  size: 262144 KB
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Max Swap size: 0 KB
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Using Least Load store dir selection
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Set Current Directory to /var/spool/squid
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Finished loading MIME types and icons.
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| HTCP Disabled.
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Pinger socket opened on FD 13
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Squid plugin modules loaded: 0
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Adaptation support is off.
    2018/01/30 10:50:00 kid1| Accepting HTTP Socket connections at local=[::]:3128 remote=[::] FD 11 flags=9
    2018/01/30 10:50:00| pinger: Initialising ICMP pinger ...
    2018/01/30 10:50:00| pinger: ICMP socket opened.
    2018/01/30 10:50:00| pinger: ICMPv6 socket opened
    2018/01/30 10:50:01 kid1| storeLateRelease: released 0 objects
    2018/01/30 11:30:00 kid1| Logfile: opening log stdio:/var/log/squid/netdb.state
    2018/01/30 11:30:00 kid1| Logfile: closing log stdio:/var/log/squid/netdb.state
    2018/01/30 11:30:00 kid1| NETDB state saved; 0 entries, 0 msec
    2018/01/30 11:40:01 kid1| Preparing for shutdown after 0 requests
    2018/01/30 11:40:01 kid1| Waiting 30 seconds for active connections to finish
    2018/01/30 11:40:01 kid1| Closing HTTP port [::]:3128
    2018/01/30 11:40:01 kid1| Closing Pinger socket on FD 13
    2018/01/30 11:40:08| Pinger exiting.
    2018/01/30 11:40:32 kid1| Shutdown: NTLM authentication.
    2018/01/30 11:40:32 kid1| Shutdown: Negotiate authentication.
    2018/01/30 11:40:32 kid1| Shutdown: Digest authentication.
    2018/01/30 11:40:32 kid1| Shutdown: Basic authentication.
    2018/01/30 11:40:32 kid1| Shutting down...
```

Comment: Anything in the squid logs?

Comment: access.log is empty and de cache.log the log was to long to paste so I pasted it in the Question

Comment: If I see correctly, Squid is only listening on port 3128 IPv6.  I saw it in the log, but should've seen it in the netstat.  I have zero experience with IPv6.  Would you mind showing your squid config too?

Comment: hmm this could be the problem, i guess that all the network here in the office is IPv4 only. maybe I need to find out how to make squid listen to port 3128 also in IPv4. I've uploaded the config file here: https://www.ime.usp.br/~feulo/squid.conf, hope it helps. and thanks in advance ;)

Comment: Try http_port  10.75.245.21:3128

Comment: Strange you didn't find TL;DR in the logs.

Comment: One more thing.  "the network here in the office is IPv4 only.".  In that case, disable IPv6 on your laptop.  See eg. https://superuser.com/questions/546788/how-to-disable-ipv6-on-debian-wheezy#693688.